# iptables improvement: log DROPped connections to unknown ports/destinations for banning with fail2ban

Tags: iptables

I'm testing the following iptables rules (ipv4) with support for logging of dropped packets. I log the drops to `/var/log/iptables.log` and then ban retrying/hammering IPs with fail2ban.

I'm no expert so I wanted to ask serverfault if my ruleset and the banning with fail2ban is any good or just some security through obscurity?

*(FYI these rules are from a host with kvm/mail/ssh)*

**iptables rules**

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [152:19775]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2727 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4949 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables INPUT:DROP: " --log-level 4
-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Comment: Looks OK although you need to allow more ICMP types, rules like these can cause chaos. ICMP messages are there for good reason, things like `fragmentation needed` should be allowed, as well as others like `port unreachable`, redirects. They may be matched as `RELATED` by the `conntrack` module but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Thank you for comment! I thought these rules would enable all icmp types My intention was to keep them all enabled. :/ I will have a look on how to keep all enabled or do you have a quick tip?

Comment: Would it be better to replace the two icmp lines with the following? `-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT` and `-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT`?

Comment: The OUTPUT rule doesn't do anything now as the policy is `ACCEPT` anyway; INPUT is a different story as there's a final `DROP` rule for everything. So, yes, accepting all icmp should be fine.